# VS2017 (15.3) + Resharper - No Angular autocompletion of components, modules, etc

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, resharper, intellisense

I am trying to develop Angular (4) apps in VS2017 with Resharper, but I have the problem that classes (modules, components, etc.) are not resolved when trying to auto complete the code by pressing `CTRL + Spacebar`.

Here writing `LayMod` should find the module `LayoutModule` in `./layout/layout.module`:

[image: LayMod should find the module LayoutModule in ./layout/layout.module]

If I write out the complete name and click somewhere else, Resharper suggests the import:

[image: Resharper suggesting the correct import statement]

This also happens for imported modules out of the `node_modules` directory, e.g. `RouterModule` from `@angular/router`.

I am using the `JavascriptServices/Angular` quickstart template included in VS2017 (15.3) with the latest stable Visual Studio (15.3) and Resharper (2017.2 EAP 12) Release.

Here is the `tsconfig.json` used:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17863. Remove this if you upgrade to a fixed version of Angular.
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "webpack-env", "jasmine" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

How can I get the autocompletion of unimported modules working in VS2017 (+Resharper)? Is it supported at all or do I have to use another editor, like Webstorm?

Comment: I suggest to try Webstorm with Angular plugin installed, it works like a charm and you event get all IntelliSense in html files. It doesn't work for me on VS + Resharper either.

Comment: I have tried webstorm and I know that it works, but I already have a license for Resharper and VS Enterprise, so I want to use the tools I have.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Angular 2 support in *ReSharper → Options → Code Editing → HTML → Editor*? See the [ReSharper help pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/Angular_Support.html).

Comment: That does not solve the problem of autocompletion inside module classes.